# Convert String to DateTime

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

What is the best way to convert a string to DateTime?

The format of the string is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

Thanks a lot,
Vincent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you considered Date.parse() (doc [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Date.html#parse()))

```
var dateParsed:String = "Sat Nov 30 1974";

var milliseconds:Number = Date.parse(dateParsed);
trace(milliseconds); // 155030400000
```

Comment: Just noticed the answer was top match on google for "flex Convert String to DateTime". Some people would kill for that rank :)